# Как получить конкретные данные в div с помощью Selenium и пользуя условие?

Tags: python, html, selenium

Допустим, на этом сайте часто меняются данные (магазины). Меня интересуют только определенные магазины из моего списка. Как мне получить все данные первого магазина из топа и из моего списка?

Я смог получить только весь список магазинов

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Bakeries')

name = ["Pat-a-Cake", "Chef Bakers"]

storenames = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name")
for i in storenames:
   rest = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name")
   print(i.text)
```

Спасибо!

Comment: `if 'my_store_name') in i.text:` в цикле по проходу по списку своих магазинов?

Comment: Спасиб....уже ближе к делу...А можно как то в этот if указать список магазинов, а не один (на подобие параметра name)

Comment: Я понял как использовать список, вот код: `код`name = ["Pat-a-Cake", "Chef Bakers"]

storenames = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name")
for i in storenames:
   if any(x in i.text for x in name):
      print(i.text)
   else:
      print ('NO') `код` Однако я теперь получаю куча NO и два "моих" магазина в соответствие со своим порядком. Как мне вывести только один магазин, находящийся всех выше по списку?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in storenames:
   if i.text in name:
       result = i.text
       break 
else:
    result = 'NO'
print(result)
```

второй вариант

```
vv =[x.text for x in storenames if x.text in name]
if vv:
   result = vv[0]
else:    
    result = 'No'
print(result)
```

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Просто незнаю как в "коротком" ответе нормально вставить код. Спасибо!

Comment: @Synthezx Удалите лишние строчки else: result = 'NO'. В моем ответе нет else :)

Comment: неа, цикл по имеющимся магазинам, так как он короче, либо будет выполнятся быстрее, так же есть возможность указать не полное название

Comment: Даже если уберу else: result = 'NO' (уже собственно сделал), скрипт все равно пишет в файл последний магазин (собственно NO - это тоже последний результат строки storenames = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name"). ) А как мне записать первую строку (первый магазин) из проверяемых? Спасибо!

Comment: УУУ Круто, спасибо! Теперь действительно выбирается первый магазин из списка. Однако, если магазинов нет (нет совпадений со списком), то выдает такую вот ошибку:     result = vv[0]  # первый элимент из списка
IndexError: list index out of range......почему то NO не печатает..

Comment: @Synthezx Обновил ответ

Comment: О! то что нужно! Единственное, а можно как то по этой позиции vv[0] найденную по нужному списку магазинов получить всю информацию по магазину? т.е. не могу понять как присоединить найденную позицию к li class="cntanr"? `код`if vv:
    mystore = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "cntanr"). text
    result = vv[0]
else:
    result = 'No'
print(result)`код`

Comment: Все же можно ли как то по заданному параметру в выборке, вывести результат другого параметра? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо! Почти то что нужно. Я дополнил код. В результате нужно, если есть такой (такие магазины), то в Excel записывает первый из списка в ячейку. Если нет - пишет в ячейку (например) - NO. Но в моем коде он записывает всегда последнее значение из найденных.

```
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
FilePath = "C:/python/pythonProject/test.xlsx" #Запись данных в Эксцель

driver.get('https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Bakeries')

name = ["Pat-a-Cake", "Chef Bakers", "Glens Bake House"]
storenames = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name")
for i in storenames:
   if i.text in name:
       result = i.text
       print(i.text)  # проверка
   else:
       result = 'NO'

bk = openpyxl.load_workbook(FilePath)
s = bk.active
s.cell(row=1, column=1).value = result
bk.save(FilePath)
```

Comment: это не форум,- один вопрос,- один ответ.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Просто не понимаю как в коротком камментарии нормально вставить код. У меня все заполняется в одну строчку (пробовал и enter и ctrl+enter)